# Demora muito a receber resultado, mesmo com AsyncTask's em paralelo

Tags: android, asynctask

Eu envio uma requisição para o servidor mas demora receber o resultado, eu percebi que a *AsyncTask* que envia a localização para o servidor a cada 1 segundo está atrapalhando.

Percebi isso depois que alterei para 3 segundos, onde enviei uma nova requisição que demorou de 1 a 3 segundos.

O código onde a AsyncTask é usada está abaixo:

```
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


                    //Atualizar GeoLocalização
                    localizacao.setUsuario(motoqueiro.getId());
                    localizacao.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                    localizacao.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

                    new GeoUpdateAsynctask().execute(localizacao);

            handler.postDelayed(this, APP_REFRESH_TIME * 1000);
        }
    }, APP_REFRESH_TIME * 1000);
}
```

Queria sugestão de algum outro método que possa usar nesse caso, já que utilizo várias *AsyncTask* paralelamente.

Comment: Se entendi bem a sua explicação, o problema está no lado do servidor, ou não?.

Comment: Não brother, o problema porque as treds devem está ficando em fila, e quando eu mando uma requisição para o servidor, só recebo quando as treads terminem de executar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você diz que está a executar várias *AsyncTask* em paralelo mas não é verdade.

As [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), por defeito, são executadas em série numa mesma *thread*, mesmo que sejam instâncias diferentes.

Para que a execução seja em paralelo terá de chamar o método [executeOnExecutor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)), passando a ele um *Executor*.

```
new GeoUpdateAsynctask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, localização);
```

Comment: Falo em paralelo, porque em outra parte da activity estou instanciando uma outra classe asynctask

Comment: Sempre que utilizar o método `execute()`, mesmo que sejam objectos diferentes, a execução é colocada numa fila sendo por isso executada em série. Para que seja executada em paralelo tem de usar o método `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)`

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Mas só uma pergunta, esse é o método mais fácil para economizar recurso?

Comment: Se quer utilizar a classe AsyncTask e quer execução em paralelo, sim.

Comment: Certo. Eu posso utilizar umas 4 AsyncTask sem problemas ?

Comment: Em principio sim, mas irá depender do que elas fazem. Em todas as AsyncTask substitua `execute()` por `executeOnExecutor()` e teste. Considere pôr o código que postou em um serviço com uma thread dedicada.